# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' - creating frequency function

Tags: list, function, python-3.x, dictionary, methods

I am taking a text file as an input and creating a function that counts which word occurs most frequently. If 2 or more words occur most frequent and are equal I will print all of those words.

```
def wordOccurance(userFile):

    userFile.seek(0)
    line = userFile.readline()
    lines = []
    while line != "":
        if line != "\n":
            line = line.lower() # making lower case
            line = line.rstrip("\n") # cleaning
            line = line.rstrip("?") #cleans the whole docoument by removing "?" 
            line = line.rstrip("!") #cleans the whole docoument by removing "!"
            line = line.rstrip(".") #cleans the whole docoument by removing "."
            line = line.split(" ") #splits the texts into space
            lines.append(line)
        line = userFile.readline() # keep reading lines from document.

    words = lines

    wordDict = {} #creates the clean word Dic, from above 
    for word in words: #
        if word in wordDict.keys():
            wordDict[word] = wordDict[word] + 1
        else:
           wordDict[word] = 1

    largest_value = max(wordDict.values())

    for k in wordDict.keys():
        if wordDict[k] == largest_value:
            print(k)

    return wordDict
```

Please help me with this function.

Comment: Which line raises the error? At some point (maybe at `wordDict[word] = 1`) you are trying to use a list as a dictionary key, which is not allowed.

Comment: This line is giving me the error message: if word in wordDict.keys():

Comment: I can't think of any way you could get that error from that line. Does the solution I posted work for you? If not, could you please post the full traceback from your error in your question so that I can help you better?

Comment: Your solution works but i dont understand it. This is my first programming course at university and i have never seen that line of code before to understand how it works. other than that thank you very much

Comment: Got it. Please see my updated answer for an explanation of that line, and also a simplified solution with nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

In this line you are creating a list of strings:

```
line = line.split(" ") #splits the texts into space
```

Then you append it to a list, so you have a list of lists:

```
lines.append(line)
```

Later you loop through that list of lists, and try to use a sublist as a key:

```
for word in words: #
    if word in wordDict.keys():
        wordDict[word] = wordDict[word] + 1
    else:
       wordDict[word] = 1  # Here you will try to assign a list (`word`) as a key, which is not allowed
```

One easy fix would be to flatten the list of lists first:

```
words = [item for sublist in lines for item in sublist]

for word in words: #
    if word in wordDict.keys():
        wordDict[word] = wordDict[word] + 1
    else:
       wordDict[word] = 1
```

The [list comprehension](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html) `[item for sublist in lines for item in sublist]` will loop through `lines`, then loop through the sublists created by `line.split(" ")` and return a new list consisting of the items in each sublist. For you, `lines` probably looks something like this:

```
[['words', 'on', 'line', 'one'], ['words', 'on', 'line', 'two']]
```

The list comprehension will turn it into this:

```
['words', 'on', 'line', 'one', 'words', 'on', 'line', 'two']
```

If you would like to use something a little less complicated, you could just use nested loops:

```
    # words = lines
    # just use `lines` in your for loop instead of creating an identical list 

    wordDict = {} #creates the clean word Dic, from above 
    for line in lines:
        for word in line:
            if word in wordDict.keys():
                wordDict[word] = wordDict[word] + 1
            else:
                wordDict[word] = 1

    largest_value = max(wordDict.values())
```

This will probably be a little less efficient and/or "Pythonic", but it will probably be easier to wrap your head around.

Also, you may want to consider splitting each line into words before cleaning the data, because if you clean the lines first, you will only remove punctuation at the end of lines rather than at the end of words. However, this might not be necessary depending on the nature of your data.